# How to put image into center?

Tags: python, fits

I have 512X512 image (image array) of circle of radius 40. But the center of circle is at (300,300) and I want to put this center of circle at the center of array at position (256,256). How can I flesh out the array so that center of the circle is in the center of the array?

Many thanks

-Viral

Comment: What kind of image? A list of lists? An `PIL.Image` object?

Comment: there are a lot of FITS online - do you mean this? http://www.cv.nrao.edu/fits/